# How to save the state(all open windows and tabs)?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

is it possible to save the current state(all open windows, tabs, connections, files, etc...), shut down SQL Developer, restart it some other day and resume work where you left?

Comment: The only solution which I know is NOT to turn off computer...

Comment: Screenshot it, shut it down, then re-open and re-position your windows according to where they were on the screenshot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I've tried it with my SQL Developer Version 4.0.3.16 Build MAIN-16.84

Every time you close SQL Developer while some tabs opened, it will opened those tabs again when you open  SQL Developer again

However, SQL Developer won't remember the connections you used to execute those SQLs. So when you try to execute those SQLs, you will prompted to choose the connection where the SQL will be executed

nb : you can also open recent files by using Navigate -> Go To Recent Files

Comment: I downloaded this latest version but it's not working. Do you have to enable anything specific to make this happen?

Comment: which version? did you use the same as mine? because i downloaded and installed this one just recently (about 2-3 weeks ago)

Comment: I have SQL Developer version 4.1.5.21 and when I reopen it it starts with no tabs opened...

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to [nobodykid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060210/2279200): It seems to me that open tabs with queries in are not displayed at next session unless they are stored to a file on disk explicitly by the user.

In other words, if you close SQL developer and you do not save your tabs as files on disk explicitly, the tabs will not be recovered upon restart.

Answer (score 0):

in task manager -> end task (PL/SQL dev.) after next open you will see offer with recover previous tabs